# Помогите пожалуйста с регуляркой

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста составить регулярку, которая подходила бы к каждой из строк ниже

Из каждой из строки пытаюсь вытащить имя, id и версию (где первая колонка - имя, вторая - id, третья - версия) и поместить их в разные переменные. Колонки разделяют пробелы. Но между колонками может быть разное количество пробелов, как и символов в этих колонках, вот с этим у меня и проблема(

```
ttth                                 yafp.ttth                                        1.8.0          Tag: google                 winget
Gmail Desktop                        timche.gmail-desktop                             2.25.3         Tag: google                 winget
Kube Forwarder                       pixel-point.kube-forwarder                       1.5.1          Tag: google                 winget
Google Assistant Preview             Melvin-Abraham.Google-Assistant.Preview          1.0.0-rc.2     Tag: google                 winget
Google Assistant                     Melvin-Abraham.Google-Assistant                  1.1.0          Tag: google                 winget
OpenDrive                            liberodark.ODrive                                0.3.0          Tag: google                 winget
Google Calendar                      klinker24.google-calendar-desktop                1.7.1          Tag: google                 winget
Electronic Gmail                     jie17.electronic-gmail                           0.0.18         Tag: google                 winget
Voice Desktop                        jerrod-lankford.google-voice-desktop-app         1.3.1          Tag: google                 winget
Google Web Designer                  Google.WebDesigner                               9.0.8.0        Tag: google                 winget
Google Play Games                    Google.PlayGames.Beta                            22.10.1285.8   Tag: google                 winget
Google Cloud SDK                     Google.CloudSDK                                  392.0.0        Tag: google                 winget
Chrome Remote Desktop Host           Google.ChromeRemoteDesktop                       111.0.5563.12  Tag: google                 winget
Crow Translate                       CrowTranslate.CrowTranslate                      2.10.3         Tag: google                 winget
比译                                 Biyi.Biyi                                        0.4.0+11       Tag: google                 winget
G Desktop Suite                      alexkim205.g-desktop-suite                       0.3.1          Tag: google                 winget
Cerebro                              AlexandrSubbotin.Cerebro                         0.11.0         Tag: google                 winget
Google Drive                         Google.Drive                                     70.0.2.0       Tag: google                 winget
Google Chrome Canary                 Google.Chrome.Canary                             112.0.5594.3   Tag: google                 winget
Google Chrome Dev                    Google.Chrome.Dev                                112.0.5582.0   Tag: google                 winget
google-chat-linux                    squalou.google-chat-linux                        5.21.19-1                                  winget
Google Play Music Desktop Player     SamuelAttard.GooglePlayMusicDesktopPlayer        4.7.1                                      winget
Outlook Google Calendar Sync (Alpha) PaulWoolcock.SyncOutlookandGooglecalendars.alpha 2.9.4-alpha                                winget
Outlook Google Calendar Sync         PaulWoolcock.SyncOutlookandGooglecalendars       2.9.0-beta                                 winget
Google 日本語入力                    Google.JapaneseIME                               2.28.4650.0                                winget
IAP Desktop                          Google.IAPDesktop                                2.33.964                                   winget
Firebase CLI Tools                   Google.FirebaseCLI                               11.22.0                                    winget
Google Earth Pro                     Google.EarthPro                                  7.3.4.8642                                 winget
Backup and Sync from Google          Google.BackupAndSync                             3.57.4043.4118                             winget
Android Studio Canary                Google.AndroidStudio.Canary                      2022.3.1.2                                 winget
Android Studio Beta                  Google.AndroidStudio.Beta                        2022.2.1.12                                winget
Android Studio                       Google.AndroidStudio                             2022.1.1.19                                winget
Chromium                             eloston.ungoogled-chromium                       110.0.5481.78                              winget
Unofficial Google Docs               CompLabs.GoogleDocs                              2022.3.10                                  winget
Google Meet                          arjun-g.google-meet-desktop                      1.2.0                                      winget
Google Chat Electron                 ankurk91.GoogleChatElectron                      2.18.0                                     winget
Google Chrome                        Google.Chrome                                    110.0.5481.97                              winget
Google Chrome Beta                   Google.Chrome.Beta                               111.0.5563.19                              winget
Wondershare InClowdz                 Wondershare.InClowdz                             2.0.9          Tag: google-drive           winget
Serverless Framework                 Serverless.Serverless                            3.27.0         Tag: google-cloud-functions winget
PremiumSoft Navicat Premium          PremiumSoft.NavicatPremium                       16.0.14        Tag: google-cloud           winget
SFTPGo                               drakkan.SFTPGo                                   v2.4.4         Tag: google-cloud-storage   winget
```

```
C:\Users\llllll>winget list
Имя                                              ИД                                                   Версия              Доступно       Источник
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Termius 7.56.1                                   Termius.Termius                                      7.56.1                             winget
7-Zip 22.01 (x64)                                7zip.7zip                                            22.01                              winget
AIMP                                             AIMP.AIMP                                            5.10.2418                          winget
Diablo III                                       Diablo III                                           Unknown
Diablo III Public Test                           Diablo III Public Test                               Unknown
Discord                                          Discord.Discord                                      1.0.9010            1.0.9011       winget
Files                                            Files_1y0xx7n9077q4                                  2.1.13.0
Google Chrome                                    Google.Chrome                                        110.0.5481.97       110.0.5481.104 winget
K-Lite Codec Pack 17.4.0 Full                    CodecGuide.K-LiteCodecPack.Full                      17.4.0                             winget
Microsoft Edge                                   Microsoft Edge                                       110.0.1587.49
Microsoft Edge Update                            Microsoft Edge Update                                1.3.173.45
Среда выполнения Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime Microsoft EdgeWebView                                110.0.1587.50
MSN Погода                                       Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe                  4.53.43112.0
Установщик приложения                            Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe          1.19.10173.0
Техническая поддержка                            Microsoft.GetHelp_8wekyb3d8bbwe                      10.2212.10101.0
Советы Майкрософт                                Microsoft.Getstarted_8wekyb3d8bbwe                   10.2210.3.0
HEIF Image Extensions                            Microsoft.HEIFImageExtension_8wekyb3d8bbwe           1.0.43012.0
Пакет локализованного интерфейса на русском      Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackru-RU_8wekyb3d8bbwe  19041.56.177.0
Paint 3D                                         Microsoft.MSPaint_8wekyb3d8bbwe                      6.2203.1037.0
Средство 3D-просмотра                            Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer_8wekyb3d8bbwe            7.2211.24012.0
Microsoft Edge                                   Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge.Stable_8wekyb3d8bbwe         110.0.1587.49
Microsoft 365 (Office)                           Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe           18.2301.1131.0
Solitaire & Casual Games                         Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_8wekyb3d8bbwe 4.15.12020.0
Записки (Майкрософт)                             Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe         4.5.9.0
Портал смешанной реальности                      Microsoft.MixedReality.Portal_8wekyb3d8bbwe          2000.21051.1282.0
OneNote for Windows 10                           Microsoft.Office.OneNote_8wekyb3d8bbwe               16001.14326.21146.0
Набросок на фрагменте экрана                     Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe                 10.2008.2277.0
Skype                                            Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c                     15.93.3408.0
Узел для покупок в Store                         Microsoft.StorePurchaseApp_8wekyb3d8bbwe             12207.44.6.0
VP9 Video Extensions                             Microsoft.VP9VideoExtensions_8wekyb3d8bbwe           1.0.52781.0
Microsoft Pay                                    Microsoft.Wallet_8wekyb3d8bbwe                       2.4.18324.0
Расширения для интернет-мультимедиа              Microsoft.WebMediaExtensions_8wekyb3d8bbwe           1.0.42192.0
Webp Image Extensions                            Microsoft.WebpImageExtension_8wekyb3d8bbwe           1.0.52351.0
Фотографии (Майкрософт)                          Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe               2022.30120.12007.0
Часы Windows                                     Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe                11.2212.2.0
Калькулятор Windows                              Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe            11.2210.0.0
Камера Windows                                   Microsoft.WindowsCamera_8wekyb3d8bbwe                2021.105.10.0
Центр отзывов                                    Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe           1.2203.761.0
Карты Windows                                    Microsoft.WindowsMaps_8wekyb3d8bbwe                  11.2210.6.0
Запись голоса Windows                            Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder_8wekyb3d8bbwe         10.2103.28.0
Microsoft Store                                  Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe                 22212.1401.8.0
Windows Package Manager Source (winget)          Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe                2023.218.129.225
Xbox TCUI                                        Microsoft.Xbox.TCUI_8wekyb3d8bbwe                    1.24.10001.0
Компаньон консоли Xbox                           Microsoft.XboxApp_8wekyb3d8bbwe                      48.89.25001.0
Xbox Game Bar Plugin                             Microsoft.XboxGameOverlay_8wekyb3d8bbwe              1.54.4001.0
Xbox Game Bar                                    Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay_8wekyb3d8bbwe            5.823.1271.0
Xbox Identity Provider                           Microsoft.XboxIdentityProvider_8wekyb3d8bbwe         12.95.3001.0
Xbox Game Speech Window                          Microsoft.XboxSpeechToTextOverlay_8wekyb3d8bbwe      1.21.13002.0
Связь с телефоном                                Microsoft.YourPhone_8wekyb3d8bbwe                    1.22122.94.0
Медиаплеер Windows                               Microsoft.ZuneMusic_8wekyb3d8bbwe                    11.2212.31.0
Кино и ТВ                                        Microsoft.ZuneVideo_8wekyb3d8bbwe                    10.22091.10031.0
NVIDIA Control Panel                             NVIDIACorp.NVIDIAControlPanel_56jybvy8sckqj          8.1.963.0
Overwatch                                        Overwatch                                            Unknown
Realtek Audio Control                            RealtekSemiconductorCorp.RealtekAudioControl_dt26b9… 1.1.137.0
Spotify                                          Spotify.Spotify                                      1.2.4.912.g949d5fd0                winget
Steam                                            Valve.Steam                                          2.10.91.91                         winget
WebStorm 2022.3.2                                JetBrains.WebStorm                                   2022.3.2                           winget
Почта и Календарь                                microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe    16005.14326.21318.0
qBittorrent                                      qBittorrent.qBittorrent                              4.5.1                              winget
Node.js                                          OpenJS.NodeJS                                        19.6.0              19.6.1         winget
JBL QuantumENGINE                                {3d3a3f2e-1efd-4b5b-9ec4-651d2078dea2}               1.13.0.1615
OpenVPN Connect                                  OpenVPNTechnologies.OpenVPNConnect                   3.3.6                              winget
Telegram Desktop                                 Telegram.TelegramDesktop                             4.6.3                              winget
WingetUI                                         SomePythonThings.WingetUIStore                       1.6.0                              winget
Microsoft Update Health Tools                    {89581302-705F-42C5-99B0-E368A845DAD5}               3.70.0.0
NVIDIA Графический драйвер 516.94                {B2FE1952-0186-46C3-BAEC-A80AA35AC5B8}_Display.Driv… 516.94
NVIDIA GeForce NOW 2.0.48.108                    Nvidia.GeForceNow                                    2.0.48.108                         winget
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable … Microsoft.VCRedist.2015+.x64                         14.34.31931.0                      winget
Python 3.9.13 (64-bit)                           Python.Python.3.9                                    3.9.13
```

```
C:\Users\llllll>winget search google
Имя                                  ИД                                               Версия         Совпадение                  Источник
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
知云文献翻译                         Yemiao.ZhiyunTranslator                          7.7.2          Tag: google                 winget
Xtranslator                          Yemiao.Xtranslator                               2.5.5          Tag: google                 winget
ttth                                 yafp.ttth                                        1.8.0          Tag: google                 winget
Gmail Desktop                        timche.gmail-desktop                             2.25.3         Tag: google                 winget
Kube Forwarder                       pixel-point.kube-forwarder                       1.5.1          Tag: google                 winget
Google Assistant Preview             Melvin-Abraham.Google-Assistant.Preview          1.0.0-rc.2     Tag: google                 winget
Google Assistant                     Melvin-Abraham.Google-Assistant                  1.1.0          Tag: google                 winget
OpenDrive                            liberodark.ODrive                                0.3.0          Tag: google                 winget
Google Calendar                      klinker24.google-calendar-desktop                1.7.1          Tag: google                 winget
Electronic Gmail                     jie17.electronic-gmail                           0.0.18         Tag: google                 winget
Voice Desktop                        jerrod-lankford.google-voice-desktop-app         1.3.1          Tag: google                 winget
Google Web Designer                  Google.WebDesigner                               9.0.8.0        Tag: google                 winget
Google Play Games                    Google.PlayGames.Beta                            22.10.1285.8   Tag: google                 winget
Google Cloud SDK                     Google.CloudSDK                                  392.0.0        Tag: google                 winget
Chrome Remote Desktop Host           Google.ChromeRemoteDesktop                       111.0.5563.12  Tag: google                 winget
Crow Translate                       CrowTranslate.CrowTranslate                      2.10.3         Tag: google                 winget
比译                                 Biyi.Biyi                                        0.4.0+11       Tag: google                 winget
G Desktop Suite                      alexkim205.g-desktop-suite                       0.3.1          Tag: google                 winget
Cerebro                              AlexandrSubbotin.Cerebro                         0.11.0         Tag: google                 winget
Google Drive                         Google.Drive                                     70.0.2.0       Tag: google                 winget
Google Chrome Canary                 Google.Chrome.Canary                             112.0.5601.0   Tag: google                 winget
Google Chrome Dev                    Google.Chrome.Dev                                112.0.5596.2   Tag: google                 winget
google-chat-linux                    squalou.google-chat-linux                        5.21.19-1                                  winget
Google Play Music Desktop Player     SamuelAttard.GooglePlayMusicDesktopPlayer        4.7.1                                      winget
Outlook Google Calendar Sync (Alpha) PaulWoolcock.SyncOutlookandGooglecalendars.alpha 2.9.4-alpha                                winget
Outlook Google Calendar Sync         PaulWoolcock.SyncOutlookandGooglecalendars       2.9.0-beta                                 winget
Google 日本語入力                    Google.JapaneseIME                               2.28.4650.0                                winget
IAP Desktop                          Google.IAPDesktop                                2.33.964                                   winget
Firebase CLI Tools                   Google.FirebaseCLI                               11.22.0                                    winget
Google Earth Pro                     Google.EarthPro                                  7.3.4.8642                                 winget
Backup and Sync from Google          Google.BackupAndSync                             3.57.4043.4118                             winget
Android Studio Canary                Google.AndroidStudio.Canary                      2022.3.1.2                                 winget
Android Studio Beta                  Google.AndroidStudio.Beta                        2022.2.1.12                                winget
Android Studio                       Google.AndroidStudio                             2022.1.1.19                                winget
Chromium                             eloston.ungoogled-chromium                       110.0.5481.78                              winget
Unofficial Google Docs               CompLabs.GoogleDocs                              2022.3.10                                  winget
Google Meet                          arjun-g.google-meet-desktop                      1.2.0                                      winget
Google Chat Electron                 ankurk91.GoogleChatElectron                      2.18.0                                     winget
Google Chrome                        Google.Chrome                                    110.0.5481.104                             winget
Google Chrome Beta                   Google.Chrome.Beta                               111.0.5563.33                              winget
Wondershare InClowdz                 Wondershare.InClowdz                             2.0.9          Tag: google-drive           winget
Serverless Framework                 Serverless.Serverless                            3.27.0         Tag: google-cloud-functions winget
PremiumSoft Navicat Premium          PremiumSoft.NavicatPremium                       16.0.14        Tag: google-cloud           winget
SFTPGo                               drakkan.SFTPGo                                   v2.4.4         Tag: google-cloud-storage   winget
```

```
C:\Users\llllll>winget search node
Имя                                                                   ИД                                Версия           Совпадение     Источник
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node Devices Smart Home                                               9PJ4RQWFHW36                      Unknown                         msstore
Document Node                                                         9PHBJJ3L6D7W                      Unknown                         msstore
Node Commander Mobile                                                 9MX5FS6VT35V                      Unknown                         msstore
Volta                                                                 Volta.Volta                       1.1.1            Command: node  winget
Node.js Nightly                                                       OpenJS.NodeJS.Nightly             20.0.0           Command: node  winget
Node.js                                                               OpenJS.NodeJS                     19.6.1           Command: node  winget
Yank Note                                                             purocean.YankNote                 3.48.2           Tag: node      winget
pnpm                                                                  pnpm.pnpm                         7.27.0           Tag: node      winget
Node.js LTS                                                           OpenJS.NodeJS.LTS                 18.14.1          Tag: node      winget
RunJS                                                                 lukehaas.RunJS                    2.7.5            Tag: node      winget
Open Video Downloader                                                 jely2002.youtube-dl-gui           2.4.0            Tag: node      winget
Grid                                                                  Ethereum.grid                     1.6.2            Tag: node      winget
Ethereum - Geth - Official Go implementation of the Ethereum protocol Ethereum.geth                     1.10.11-7231b3ef Tag: node      winget
NVM for Windows                                                       CoreyButler.NVMforWindows         1.1.10           Tag: node      winget
Trading Paints                                                        Rhinode.TradingPaints             2.0.37                          winget
Renode                                                                Renode.Renode                     1.13.2                          winget
NodemailerApp                                                         nodemailer.nodemailer             1.0.16                          winget
PxCook                                                                FancyNode.PxCook                  v3.9.960 Beta                   winget
Corda Node Explorer                                                   corda.node-explorer               0.1.2                           winget
ttth                                                                  yafp.ttth                         1.8.0            Tag: freenode  winget
QQ小程序开发者工具                                                    Tencent.qq-devtool                0.70.2209190     Tag: nodejs    winget
Nodist                                                                Nodist.Nodist                     0.9.1.0          Tag: node.js   winget
Laragon                                                               LeNgocKhoa.Laragon                5.0.0.210523     Tag: nodejs    winget
CodeLite                                                              CodeLite.CodeLite                 15.0.0           Tag: nodejs    winget
Chia                                                                  ChiaNetwork.GUIforChiaBlockchain  1.7.0            Tag: full-node winget
Cactus Blockchain                                                     CactusNetwork.CactusBlockchainGUI 1.3.4            Tag: full-node winget
```

Пытался вырезать через substring

```
const str = '7-Zip 22.01 (x64)                                7zip.7zip                                            22.01               winget'
const name = str.substring(0, 45).trim() // 7-Zip 22.01 (x64)
const id = str.substring(45, 90).trim() // 7zip.7zip
const version = str.substring(90, 110).trim() // 22.01
```

Но это работает ровно до того момента, как в строке попадаются китайские символы(

Comment: Из каждой из строки пытаюсь вытащить имя, id и версию (где первая колонка - имя, вторая - id, третья - версия) и поместить их в разные переменные.
Колонки разделяют пробелы.
Но между колонками может быть разное количество пробелов, как и символов в этих колонках, вот с этим у меня и проблема(

Comment: Если взять строчку ``Outlook Google Calendar Sync (Alpha) PaulWoolcock.SyncOutlookandGooglecalendars.alpha 2.9.4-alpha                                winget``, то непонятно, где тут заканчивается одна "колонка" и начинается другая.

Comment: Такой вот вывод из консоли =( 
https://i.ibb.co/mGcFJ5g/image.png

Comment: колонки "Источник" и "Совпадение" нужны?

Comment: @Эникейщик, Нет, не нужны

Comment: Обязательно регулярное выражение? Или без него можно?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy можно и без него

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос строки с точками в имени и с многоточиями. Текстом.

Comment: На картинке с консолью в выводе `winget` есть строка с заголовком. Её можно использовать для восстановления размера колонок и безошибочного разбора остального текста. Если вас устраивает такое решение, добавьте в примеры заголовки.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy обновил

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy но так снова будет проблема с китайскими символами..

Comment: Я пишу парсер, который выставляет колонки по заголовку а затем корректирует их по отдельным строкам. И китайские символы и разные колонки - всё будет обработатно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пару слов про причину явления. А причина - стремление к красоте.

Дело не в кодировке. Обычный символ занимает в консоли одно знакоместо, иероглиф - два. При форматировании программа учитывает это (а для этого надо знать как устроен шрифт) и ровняет столбцы (удаляет пробелы) чтобы выглядело хорошо. Мой редактор тоже знает про шрифт и тоже выводит текст ровными колонками. Но Javascript работает без информации о шрифтах: с его точки зрения таблица кривая - вторая колонка выровнена на разные позиции. Но это можно поправить.

Предположим что мы знаем что второй столбец начинается с позиции 37 или раньше (если в первом есть иероглифы).

Идея в том чтобы оставить от строки 38 символов с начала и отыскать начало последнего слова (`/\S+\s*$/u`). От этого начала все отступы вправо фиксированные (если правее иероглифов нет).

```
 // исходная строка
 "Crow Translate                       CrowTranslate.CrowTranslate                      2.10.3         Tag: google                 winget"
 // 38 символов
 "Crow Translate                       C"
 //                                    на позиции 37 начинается id

 // исходная строка
 "比译                                Biyi.Biyi                                       0.4.0+11       Tag: google                 winget"
 // 38 символов
 "比译                                Biy"
 //                                  на позиции 35 начинается id
```

Попутно оказалось что `winget` подбирает ширину колонок по содержимому. Восстановить конкретную ситуацию помогает заголовок. Все наименования колонок состоят из одного слова. Новая колонка начинается с нового слова в заголовке. Регулярное выражение `/\S+/ug` выбирает слова из заголовка.

Реализация идеи:

```
const makeParse = (title, cb) => {
    const widths = [];
    const keys = [];
    {
        const title_re = /\S+/ug;
        const m = title_re.exec(title);
        keys.push(m[0]);
        let lastIndex = m.index; // should be zero
        while (true) {
            const m = title_re.exec(title);
            if (m === null) {
                break;
            }
            keys.push(m[0]);
            widths.push(m.index - lastIndex)
            lastIndex = m.index;
        }
    }

    return line => {
        if (line === '-'.repeat(line.length)) {
            return;
        }

        const indices = [
            0,
            line.substring(0, widths[0] + 1).match(/\S+\s*$/u).index
        ];
        for (let i = 1; i < widths.length; ++i) {
            indices.push(indices[i] + widths[i]);
        }
        indices.push(line.length);

        const record = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
            record[keys[i]] = line.substring(indices[i], indices[i + 1]).trim();
        }
        cb(record);
    };
};

(() => {
    const rl = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
        terminal: false
    });

    let parse = undefined;
    const records = [];

    rl.on('line', line => {
        if (parse === undefined) {
            parse = makeParse(line, r => records.push(r));
        } else {
            parse(line);
        }
    });
    rl.once('close', () => process.stdout.write(
        JSON.stringify(records, undefined, 4) + '\n'
    ));
})();
```

> ```
> $ cat data.txt
> Имя                                  ИД                                                Версия              Совпадение  Источник
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 知云文献翻译                         Yemiao.ZhiyunTranslator                           7.7.2               Tag: google winget
> Xtranslator                          Yemiao.Xtranslator                                2.5.5               Tag: google winget
> ttth                                 yafp.ttth                                         1.8.0               Tag: google winget
> Gmail Desktop                        timche.gmail-desktop                              2.25.3              Tag: google winget
> Outlook Google Calendar Sync (Alpha) PaulWoolcock.SyncOutlookandGooglecalendars.alpha  2.9.4-alpha                     winget
> Google 日本語入力                    Google.JapaneseIME                                2.28.4650.0                     winget
> Почта и Календарь                    microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe 16005.14326.21318.0
> A                                    B                                                 C                   D           E
> A a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a aA B b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b B C c c c c c c c c C D d d d d D E e e eE
>
> $ node parse.js < data.txt 
> [
>     {
>         "Имя": "知云文献翻译",
>         "ИД": "Yemiao.ZhiyunTranslator",
>         "Версия": "7.7.2",
>         "Совпадение": "Tag: google",
>         "Источник": "winget"
>     },
>     {
>         "Имя": "Xtranslator",
>         "ИД": "Yemiao.Xtranslator",
>         "Версия": "2.5.5",
>         "Совпадение": "Tag: google",
>         "Источник": "winget"
>     },
>     {
>         "Имя": "ttth",
>         "ИД": "yafp.ttth",
>         "Версия": "1.8.0",
>         "Совпадение": "Tag: google",
>         "Источник": "winget"
>     },
>     {
>         "Имя": "Gmail Desktop",
>         "ИД": "timche.gmail-desktop",
>         "Версия": "2.25.3",
>         "Совпадение": "Tag: google",
>         "Источник": "winget"
>     },
>     {
>         "Имя": "Outlook Google Calendar Sync (Alpha)",
>         "ИД": "PaulWoolcock.SyncOutlookandGooglecalendars.alpha",
>         "Версия": "2.9.4-alpha",
>         "Совпадение": "",
>         "Источник": "winget"
>     },
>     {
>         "Имя": "Google 日本語入力",
>         "ИД": "Google.JapaneseIME",
>         "Версия": "2.28.4650.0",
>         "Совпадение": "",
>         "Источник": "winget"
>     },
>     {
>         "Имя": "Почта и Календарь",
>         "ИД": "microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe",
>         "Версия": "16005.14326.21318.0",
>         "Совпадение": "",
>         "Источник": ""
>     },
>     {
>         "Имя": "A",
>         "ИД": "B",
>         "Версия": "C",
>         "Совпадение": "D",
>         "Источник": "E"
>     },
>     {
>         "Имя": "A a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a aA",
>         "ИД": "B b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b B",
>         "Версия": "C c c c c c c c c C",
>         "Совпадение": "D d d d d D",
>         "Источник": "E e e eE"
>     }
> ]
> ```

Comment: Идеально!) Но, оказалось что в первой колонке может быть и больше символов, впервые такое увидел(

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

зачем JS, если есть PS

```
$wingetOutput = winget search google
$regexPattern = "(?<Name>.+)\s+(?<Id>.+)\s+(?<Version>.+)"
$wingetOutput -match $regexPattern | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $Matches["Name"]
    $id = $Matches["Id"]
    $version = $Matches["Version"]
    Write-Output "Name: $name, Id: $id, Version: $version"
}
```

Comment: `Name: Gmail, Id: Desktop, Version: timche.gmail-desktop`?

Comment: Ответ изменился, но мой вопрос остался: строки с пробелами в имени буду разобраны правильно?